# Remove File Extension for Page Outside of WordPress

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to add a plaintext page to my server that is outside of WordPress (it can't have any HTML on it). I created the page off of public_html, but I have to add a `.html` extension to get the page to load or else it goes to a 404. The problem is that I have to have the file extension removed. I have tried adding the code below to the top of the `.htaccess` file, but it still is not removing the `.html`.

Example link: `https://example.com/apple-app-site-association.html` needs to be `https://example.com/apple-app-site-association/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: To clarify, you are adding just ONE page outside of WordPress? Your directive is effectively adding `.php` to "every" URL?? (Also, it's obviously adding `.php`, not `.html`, which seems to be the desired extension?) Note that you don't use `.htaccess` to "remove" the file extension, as you seem to suggest - it should already be removed in your link (which I'm sure is more desirable - otherwise your users will see it). `.htaccess` is then used to _append_ the extension (to map the URL to the actual filesystem path that handles the request).

Comment: Yes it is a page with plain text on it for an app. I realize I forgot to change that to .html but that still didn't remove the extension. I need WordPress to ignore this page but be accessible without any file extension. Here is a screenshot of where the file exists currently - [link](https://tinyurl.com/y8hj8gwp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...but that still didn't remove the extension.

To be clear, the extension should already be removed in the HTML anchor/link. The purpose of `.htaccess` is primarily to rewrite the extensionless URL back to the underlying filesystem path (which contains the file extension).

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

Apart from rewriting to `.php`, not `.html` (as stated), this is far too generic. You only appear to have 1 URL that needs to be rewritten, but this rewrites *everything* that doesn't contain a dot - which probably includes all your WordPress URLs as well!

This will also fail if the requested URL ends in a trailing slash - as in your example.

Bit of an aside, but... the preceding condition (that checks that the request does not map to a file) is most probably unnecessary here anyway, since you are only matching requests that do not contain a dot (ie. do not contain a file extension) - it is unlikely that a URL without a "file extension" maps directly to a file on the filesystem. (This would mean you have files without file extensions - which is generally a bad idea.)

So, providing you are already linking to `https://example.com/apple-app-site-association/` (as stated - *with* a trailing slash) then add the following *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
Options -MultiViews

# Rewrite "/url/" to "/url.html"
RewriteRule ^(apple-app-site-association)/$ $1.html [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
:
```

The `$1` backreference is simply to save repetition.

There is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive (since this is already included in the WordPress block below - the order does not matter). Include the `Options` directive to disable MultiViews if not already.

---

**UPDATE:** If the file really is "plaintext" (and "can't have any HTML on it") as you say, then why not use the `.txt` extension instead of `.html`? By using `.html`, Apache will send a mime-type of `text/html`, as opposed to `text/plain` (as with a `.txt` extension), which would seem to be the desired outcome? Browsers also format `text/plain` documents differently by default using a monospaced font.